# Java Mail showing Authenitcation failure

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using java mail to send mail from server. I'm using the below code but I get this error..

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at mail.mailSSL.main(mailSSL.java:53)
 Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at mail.mailSSL.main(mailSSL.java:48)
```

My code:

```
public class mailSSL {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("raviteja.satyavda@gmail.com","raviteja@it");
                }
            });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("raviteja.satyavada@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("ravitejas89@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("SFTS MAIL TESING");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: you may want to edit and replace your password with "*"s in the post above. Have you tried the plain and simple mail.smtp.user or mail.smtp.password ?

Answer (score 1):

Your class worked perfectly with my credentials. Do you have a Gmail account? When I tried yours (through the code) I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at                   
535 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ib2sm1330072vdb.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would belive that there is a message exception that is not being caught.